# Getting wordpress categories for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get custom post type categories and for each of these categories the posts.

This is the code that I have till now

```
function display_receipess($atts){
    $postArg = array(
        'post_type'=>'receipe',
        'posts_per_page'=>-1,
        'order'=>'desc',
    );

    $getPost = new wp_query($postArg);
    global $post;
    if($getPost->have_posts()){
        echo '<div class="row">';
            while ( $getPost->have_posts()):$getPost->the_post();
                $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'category' );
                echo '<div class="xol-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 
col-lg-3">';
                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                    echo "<h4>".$term_name = $term->name.'</h4>';
                    echo "<p>".$post->post_title."</p>";
                }

                echo '</div>';

            endwhile;
        echo '</div>';
    }


}
```

It's working fine to get the categories of my custom post type but if one category have more then one post it creates the same category in another div. If one category has more then one post it should display that under that category and not the same category each time

[Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beAXW.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solved your problem

```
<?php
    // get all the categories from the database
    $cats = get_categories(); 

    // loop through the categries
    foreach ($cats as $cat) {
            // setup the cateogory ID
            $cat_id= $cat->term_id;
            // Make a header for the cateogry

            // create a custom wordpress query
            query_posts("cat=$cat_id&posts_per_page=100&post_type=post");
            // start the wordpress loop!
            if (have_posts()){
                echo "<h2>".$cat->name."</h2>";
                while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

                <?php endwhile; 
            } 
    } // done the foreach statement 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , it didn't work. With the source code that i posted im able to get the categories the only issue is that where there are more then 1 post in the same category it dispalys the same category twice with different posts. https://prnt.sc/nc4ob5